# Exception passing in python flask app inside a POST request handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I have a python flask app, pseudocode shown below.

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
    def transformation():
       try:
           var1 = function_1()
           # do something with var1
           var2 = function_2()
       except Exception as e:
           return jsonify({'message': '{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__, e)}), 500
```

As you see, the `POST` call handler returns a generic exception message back to the client. But I want to customize those exception messages based on whether they are coming from `function_1` or `function_2`

I looked into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095717/python-one-try-multiple-except/6095782) and understand that it is possible to do below -

```
try:
 #something1
 #something2
except ExceptionType1:
 #return xyz
except ExceptionType2:
 #return abc
```

But how would it know that `ExceptionType1` is coming from `function_1()` or `function_2()`. How should I pass exception from `function_1()` or `function_2()` to be caught in the main `try-except` block?

Comment: Have you tried having two separate try-except blocks? So, like, one for function1 that will do something and another for function2?

Comment: @SaberNomen I understand that is one way of doing it. But my main try-except block has 5-6 functions so was looking for a more generic way

Comment: You could catch the exceptions in each function and `raise` a custom Exception for the route to catch.

Comment: @BrendanMartin can you show an example of how to raise a custom exception? My understanding is I need to override Exception class. But not sure how exactly

Comment: Also, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380073/how-to-identify-what-function-call-raise-an-exception-in-python