# Python: using try/except for a multi-step flow

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

Let's assume that we have the following flow:

```py
def flow(input_val: Any) -> Any:

    result1 = function1(input_val)
    result2 = function2(result1)
    result3 = function3(result2)

    return result3
```

And let's say that I want to be able to catch exceptions for each of these three steps:

```py
def flow(input_val: Any) -> Any:
    
    try:
        result1 = function1(input_val)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Function 1 error: "+str(ex))

    try:
        result2 = function2(result1)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Function 2 error: "+str(ex))

    try:
        result3 = function3(result2)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Function 3 error: "+str(ex))

    return result3
```

This doesn't look like the best way of handling exceptions in a flow like this, because if the first exception is caught, then `result1` won't be defined. Also, if the third exception is caught, there won't be anything to return.

What's the best way of handling these situations?

Comment: The problem is that you are effectively *ignoring* the exception (you catch it, but then just log it and move on as if it never happened). You either need to *provide* a definition of `result1` so your code can continue, return early, or raise an exception (the same one you just caught or a new one) to prevent the rest of `flow` from trying to execute without `result1`.

Comment: Just because an exception could be or is raised doesn't mean you *must* catch it. The whole point of exception handling is to let exceptions you can't do anything about bubble up to someone who *can* do something with it.

Comment: if `function1` raises, do you really want to attempt `function2`?

Comment: Perhaps not orthodoxically, I'm trying to use the try/except block to figure out which function in my flow failed.

Comment: use nested try-except blocks and set the variables to None before entering the try blocks

Comment: Silently passing errors is generally a bad idea. You should take a more graceful approach instead, you could try returning a failure code (0, None, -1, any would work) for an exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify what function call raise an exception in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380073/how-to-identify-what-function-call-raise-an-exception-in-python)

Comment: The stack trace will tell you *which* function produced the exception. You don't need to catch it for debugging, only in an attempt to keep your program running *despite* the error.

Comment: There are mutliple use cases. You could have a single outer try/except that logs the exception if that's all you need. You could assign default values to the variables for cleanup in a finally clause. If you need to change your code behavior based on exception... then maybe these functions should have been returning an error code instead of raising exceptions. The is an argument that exceptions should only be exceptional - exactly because of what you see here. When you need detailed control of error handling, they are a pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the functions sequentially in a "happy path" mindset and set a context variable (before each step) that you then use in your error handling logic.

```
def flow(input_val: Any) -> Any:
    
    try:
        context = "Function 1"
        result1 = function1(input_val)
        context = "Function 2"
        result2 = function2(result1)
        context = "Function 3"
        result3 = function3(result2)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(context," error: "+str(ex))
        return None

    return result3
```

*This gives you the same level of control but keeps the normal sequence of code together instead of having the intended logic drowned in error handling code.*

Answer (score 2):

If you don't catch an exception, `flow` will immediately terminate and the caller will have to catch the exception or terminate itself. This implies that if you *do* catch the exception, you need to do something more than just log that it happened. If `function1` raises an exception, `result1` is not set, so you *cannot* proceed unless you provide a value yourself. Otherwise, you should return immediately or raise an exception (the same one you just caught, or a new one).

```
# Option 1
def flow(input_val: Any) -> Any:
    
    try:
        result1 = function1(input_val)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Function 1 error: "+str(ex))
        result1 = 5

    ...
```

---

```
# Option 2
def flow(input_val: Any) -> Any:
    
    try:
        result1 = function1(input_val)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Function 1 error: "+str(ex))
        return

    ...
```

---

```
# Option 3a
def flow(input_val: Any) -> Any:
    
    try:
        result1 = function1(input_val)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Function 1 error: "+str(ex))
        raise  # Give someone else a crack at ex
    
    ...
```

---

```
# Option 3b
def flow(input_val: Any) -> Any:
    
    try:
        result1 = function1(input_val)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Function 1 error: "+str(ex))
        raise SomeOtherException("Function 1 failed")

    ...
```

Comment: Option 2 sounds interesting: the flow is stopped with a `return` call that outputs nothing. But what about the rest of the flow? If the first try is successful, is `result1` available to the next try-except block to use?

Comment: Yes; `try` blocks do not start a new scope. Assuming `function1` does not raise, its returned value is assigned to `result1` and `result1` remains in scope as you execute the next `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, try-except blocks

```
 def flow(input_val: Any) -> Any:
    
        input_val = <insert some value>
    
        result1 = None
        try:
            result1 = function1(input_val)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("error: " + str(ex))
            return None, None, None
    
        result2 = None
        try:
            result2 = function2(result1)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("error: " + str(ex))
            return result1, None, None
    
        result3 = None
        try:
            result3 = function3(result2)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("error: " + str(ex))
            return result1, result2, None
    
        return result1, result2, result3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop, if all your sequentially called functions take the last result as argument:

```
def function1(arg):
    argValue = arg + 1
    return argValue
function2, function3 = function1,function1

def flow(input_val):
    result = [input_val]
    for fn in (function1, function2, function3):
        try:
            result.append(fn(result[-1]))
        except:
            print("Error@%s" % fn.__name__)
            return
    return result # or result[-1] in order to return last result only!

print(flow(0))
```

Out:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> I'm trying to use the try/except block to figure out which function in
> my flow failed.

I believe what you are after is to catch the exception and use its traceback to get the "name" of the offending function. This seems like a much more generic approach to me:

```py
import traceback

def function1(i):
    return i

def function2(i):
    return i/0

def function3(i):
    return i

def flow(input_val):
    try:
        return function3(function2(function1(input_val)))
    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.extract_tb(e.__traceback__)
        print(f"Failure from: \"{tb[-1][2]}\"")

## -------------------
## Note: still prints None as you don't re-cast e
## -------------------
print(flow(10))
## -------------------
```

This will result in:

```
Failure from: "function2"
None
```